# ReduxForm - React Error - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have read all the questions related to my problem but it was a bit different.

I receive this error message after compiling my code:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child 
(found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, displayName, 
isLoading, fields, people, saveStatus, onSubmit, defaultProps}).
 If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

## MyForm.jsx

This is the component that I believe has the problem. I tried to remove the list *{name, ..., course}* and replace with *element* but I received the same error. Thank you in advance.

```
import { savePeople } from '../ReduxConfiguration/actions';

class Form extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    people: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    saveStatus: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    fields: PropTypes.object,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  state = {
    fields: this.props.fields || {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      course: null,
      department: null
    },
    fieldErrors: {}
  };

  validate() {
    const person = this.state.fields;
    const fieldErrors = this.state.fieldErrors;
    const errMessages = Object.keys(fieldErrors.filter(k => fieldErrors[k]));
    if (!person.name) return true;
    if (!person.email) return true;
    if (!person.course) return true;
    if (!person.department) return true;
    if (errMessages.length) return true;

    return false;
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(update) {
    console.log('this.props.fields', this.props.fields, update);
    this.setState({ fields: update.fields });
  }

  onFormSubmit = evt => {
    const person = this.state.fields;
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (this.validate()) return;
    this.props.onSubmit([...this.props.people, person]);
  };

 render() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      return <img alt="loading" src="/img/loading.gif" />;
    }
    const dirty = Object.keys(this.state.fields).length;
    let status = this.props.saveStatus;
    if (status === 'SUCCESS' && dirty) status = 'READY';
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Amazing Signup Form</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <Field
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            value={this.state.fields.name}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            validate={val => (val ? false : 'Name Required')}
          />
          <br />
          <Field
            placeholder="Email"
            name="email"
            value={this.state.fields.email}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            validate={val => (isEmail(val) ? false : 'Invalid Email')}
          />
          <br />
          {/* <CourseSelect
    department={this.state.fields.department}
    course={this.state.fields.course}
    onChange={this.onInputChange}
    /> */}
          <br />
          {
            {
              SAVING: <input value="Saving ..." type="submit" disabled />,
              SUCCESS: <input value="Saved!" type="submit" disabled />,
              ERROR: (
                <input
                  value="Save Failed - Retry?"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={this.validate}
                />
              ),
              READY: (
                <input value="Submit" type="submit" disabled={this.validate} />
              )
            }[status]
          }
        </form>
        <div>
          <h3>People</h3>
          <ul>
            {this.props.people.map(({ name, email, department, course }) => (
              <li key={new Date()}> {[name, email, department, course].join(' - ')}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
    fields: state.person,
    people: state.people,
    saveStatus: state.saveStatus
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSubmit: people => {
      dispatch(savePeople(people));
    }
  };
};
Form = reduxForm({ form: 'contact', validate: Form.validate });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Comment: `<li key={new Date()}` <- this is wronger than wrong. Most likely can be replaced with `<li key={email}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this makes problem for sure:

```
{
            {
              SAVING: <input value="Saving ..." type="submit" disabled />,
              SUCCESS: <input value="Saved!" type="submit" disabled />,
              ERROR: (
                <input
                  value="Save Failed - Retry?"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={this.validate}
                />
              ),
              READY: (
                <input value="Submit" type="submit" disabled={this.validate} />
              )
            }[status]
          }
```

Here, you are trying to render object which is not valid react child. Remove it and see if error stil persist.

Comment: The problem still persists unfortunately, but I actually doubt I should have this object here

Comment: Can you create demo on codesandbox.io so I could try to debug? Btw, what makes you doubt that object should be there?

Comment: I have never seen an object like this in a JSX file. I am learning from a textbook called Fullstack React. I will create the demo shortly.

Comment: Hey, sorry I took long. Here is a link to my demo https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-microservice-f7f2k

Comment: No problem. Sorry, can't take a look into it now, but will late tonight or tomorrow

Comment: Is [this](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/) a book from which you are learning?

Comment: Also, did you have [this app](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-microservice-f7f2k)  being functional at any point in time?

Comment: No. It never functioned

Comment: Well, thing is that debbuging could take hours. Besides, I have no idea how app should work so making error go away and app to render - doesn't necessarily means that app will work. So, will leave you here with advice to build apps incrementally - starting from simple and going to more complex architecture and functionality. That way you will always keep track when issue appears which is easear for debugging and in my oppinion - more natural flow